# My Roblox Chat is stuck to the bottom of my screen

Tags: mobile, roblox

This is tricky to explain, but in a few roblox games I play, my chat seems to be glued to the bottom of my screen. All I did was reinstall the app to fix a glitch and it happened. I have an example of it, but can somebody please help?
[image: On the left, the chat is to the bottom of my screen, and I cannot move it or edit the side of it.]